# AVAssetExportSession Error -11820 Cannot Complete Export

Tags: ios, avassetexportsession

I'm using an AVComposition to merge two .m4a audio files together. One has to be inserted in the other one at a specific time. I then use an AVAssetExportSession to save the merge audio.

I'm getting this error during the Export Session Completion Handler:

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11820 "Cannot Complete Export" UserInfo=0x1c3760 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try exporting again., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Complete Export}
```

Code - Merging the two assets:

```
  AVAsset *originalAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];
NSURL *recordingAssetUrl = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()] URLByAppendingPathComponent:kRecordTemp];
AVAsset *recordingAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:recordingAssetUrl];

AVMutableComposition *composition = [AVMutableComposition new];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *audioTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio 
                                                                 preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

//Add the original audio asset to the composition
AVAssetTrack *sourceAudioTrack = [[originalAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
NSError *error = nil;
CMTimeRange sourceRange = CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, 1), originalAsset.duration);
[audioTrack insertTimeRange:sourceRange ofTrack:sourceAudioTrack atTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, 1) error:&error];
if (error) [self showError:error];

//Remove the portion of the original audio asset that will be replaced by the recording
CMTimeRange overwrittenRange = CMTimeRangeMake(self.currentTime, recordingAsset.duration);
[audioTrack removeTimeRange:overwrittenRange];

//Add the recording asset to the composition
AVAssetTrack *recordAudioTrack = [[recordingAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
error = nil;
CMTimeRange recordRange = CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, 1), recordingAsset.duration);
[audioTrack insertTimeRange:recordRange ofTrack:recordAudioTrack atTime:self.currentTime error:&error];
if (error) [self showError:error];

//Delete the original asset
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:url.path]){
    error = nil;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:url error:&error];
    if(error) [self showError:error];
}

//Write the composition
AVAssetExportSession * exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:composition 
                                                                         presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A]; 
exportSession.outputURL = url;
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;

[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    if(exportSession.status != AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted){
        [self showError:exportSession.error];
    }
}];

//Delete the temporary asset
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:recordingAssetUrl.path]){
    error = nil;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:recordingAssetUrl error:&error];
    if(error) [self showError:error]; //BOOM it blows up here
}
```

I'm not sure what other piece of code I should paste since it's such a generic error.

I'm using an AVAssetWriter to write the sample buffer to create the recording asset I receive from the capture session. The capture session successfully records and saves into files into the urls used in the above listing.

Comment: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, 1) ? 
do you want to start from the asset from 0 seconds ..

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in what I wanted to do. I want to take everything from the recordingAsset and overwrite the originalAssset with it at self.currentTime.

Comment: tri replacing CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, 1) with kCMTimeZero

Comment: still the same. but the code is cleaner :)

Comment: hmm I commented the code deleting the origin asset and changed the export session's url and it works. I guess I'll have to export in a temporary file then delete the original asset on export completion and move the export temporary file.